# Distinct on or unique in QGIS (no postgis)

Tags: qgis-2

I have a shapefile layer which contains mutliple lines (rivers). If i label the layer it will add the river name for each segment of rivers line resulting in mtuliple names along the river. As image
[image]

As a quick work round i wanted to use the filter with distinct or unique then use this a label layer. But i run in to a problem when using

```
select distinct "name"
from layername
```

The error comes from

```
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: SELECT from table name failed, no such table/featureclass
```

How do i find the table name if it's not my layer name?

Comment: Isn't activating "merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels" in labeling settings enough?

Comment: I've tried that but same results, might be error in geometry that means lines aren't fully connected

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark), usually `"merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels"` would solve such situation. However, as in your reply, it does not work if the line segments are not connected. In other words, the endpoints of these adjacent line segments have to be at the same location.

As a workaround, you can collect these line segments into a `Multipart` object, by `Single parts to Multipart` tool. The output will behave as if it is one continuous river (obviously it is not).

[image]

As the multipart layer loses many original attributes, please use this layer only for label display, and keep your original layer.

Answer (score 0):

He,
Maybe you can try to make a new name field in the Attribute Table. I cannot know if this is what you need from your question, but it is a method for making a custom self made name filed that I find useful.
First you need to open the Attribute Table  [image] one an editing mode[image]
Then click on the "New Field" icon. [image].
The "Add Field" window will open.[image]
You can name this new field however you like, but you must make it as a "Text (string" Type and make sure that you have enough Length. I am always taping a  ridiculous long number, just in case. If you Type "3" in this bar you will be able only to add three letters and so on.
In this new row you can add the names you need to display on your map.
I am hopping that this was helpful for you.
Nitzan